# why mouseover only works for the first row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to have a mouseover action in the rows for a table but it ONLY works for the first row. I am not su what could be the issue here. Below is my code.
the CSS is inside  a file:

```
.hover{
background-color: #d3d3d3;
}



<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tableResults tr').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
});

</script>


<table  id="tableResults" class="table_border_all_around">
<tr>
<th class="header_table" style="width:auto;">PreOrder transaction ID</th>
<th class="header_table"  style="width:auto;">Partner Order ID</th>
<th class="header_table"  style="width:auto;">Order Handler</th>
<th class="header_table"  style="width:auto;">Qwest Order ID</th>
<th class="header_table"  style="width:auto;">TN</th>
<th class="header_table"  style="width:auto;">Order Status</th>
<th class="header_table"  style="width:auto;">Order Status Code</th>
<th class="header_table"  style="width:auto;">Order Status Message</th>
<th class="header_table"  style="width:auto;">Order Status Date</th>
<th class="header_table"  style="width:auto;">Order  status Time</th>
</tr>
<?php
if(!is_null($this->Orders)){?>
<?php 
foreach ($this->Orders as $order){

?>
<tr>
<td ><?php echo $this->escape($order->PreOrderTransactionId)?></td>
<td  ><?php echo $this->escape($order->PartnerOrderId)?></td>
<td ><?php echo $this->escape($order->OrderHandler)?></td>
<td ><?php echo $this->escape($order->QwestOrderId)?></td>
<td  ><?php echo $this->escape($order->TN)?></td>
<td ><?php echo$this->escape($order->OrderStatus)?></td>
<td ><?php echo $this->escape($order->OrderStatusCode)?></td>
<td ><?php echo $this->escape($order->OrderStatusMessage)?></td>
<td ><?php echo $this->escape($order->OrderStatusDate)?></td>
<td ><?php echo $this->escape($order->OrderStatusTime)?></td>
</tr>
<?php }
}?>
</table>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Don't do that.  Use the `:hover` selector.

Comment: Follow SLaks advise, and when posting this kind of question please provide rendered HTML

Comment: Can you give a sample of the :hover selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use css:s `:hover` selector. That acts like jQuery's `.hover` or `.onmouse*` functions. That's easier, and doesn't require jQuery or javascript. Below my example for using pure css:

```
#tableResults tr:hover{
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
```

Remember to remove your jquery code. :)

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/73J6k/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tableResults tr').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
}).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

**DEMO :** http://jsfiddle.net/A5bsS/